# Query mongodb using $near inside an array of Latitude and longitude object

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, geo

I'm looking to get a proximity of users within an area by using the $near operator in mongodb and I'm unsure of the correct way to do so.

In my route I have a JavaScript model (mongoose) looking up users that are local to the proximity:

```
User.find({
  $elemMatch: {
    locations: {
      $near: coords,
      $maxDistance: maxDistance
    }
  }
}).then(users => res.json(users))
```

The schema design:

```
  first_name: String,
  last_name: String,
  locations: [
    {
      suburb: String,
      state: String,
      postcode: String,
      longitude: Number,
      latitude: Number
    }
  ]
```

Each user has many locations and each has latitude and longitude. I tried $elemMatch with no success and I'm not sure if I need to aggregate or use a different operator.